# How to flag parcels as being within stop type dependent distance of transit stops?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, table, proximity

first question here!

I have a parcel layer and a transit stop layer.  The transit stop layer has different bus stops, light rail stops, etc.

I want to add to my parcel layer attribute table fields that say if said parcel is w/in the buffer of each kind of stop.

the attribute table for my parcel layer would end up looking like

```
Parcelid  Muni Bart Bus OtherAttribute
1         1    0    1   189
2         1    1    0   130423
```

Where 1 is if the parcel is w/in the radius of the type of stop and 0 if it is not.

Is this sort of thing possible in ArcGIS, or do I have to write something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Buffer stops with no merge.
2. Intersect parcels with the buffer layer.
   You want a unique ID in the parcel layer to go into the output.
3. Create your attribute fields in your original parcel table.
4. Join the intersect layer to the original parcel layer.
5. Calculate the buffer intersects to the fields.
   This is all assuming that there is a logical association between 1 buffer and 1 or more parcels.  There will be a little confusion if more than 1 stop buffer are overlapping 1 parcel. But still not impossible.
   Edit your question if you have that situation.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, using your parcel and a transit stop layers I would:

1. Add three short integer fields for Muni, Bart and Bus onto your parcel layer - from Attribute Table window or using Add Field tool
2. Copy your transit stop layer three times and name those layers Muni Stops, Bart Stops and Bus Stops - setting a **Definition Query** on each of something like **"STOP_TYPE" = 'Muni'**,
3. Repeat steps 4 and 5 below three times - once each for Muni Stops, Bart Stops and Bus Stops layers - I'll just show the example for Muni Stops
4. Use **Selection | Select By Location** (or Select Layer By Location tool) with settings below (change search distance to be appropriate for each stop type)
5. Use **Field Calculator** (or Calculate Field tool) to calculate **Muni = 1** on parcels currently selected

[image]

Using this technique means no additional spatial data is created in the process - all can be done from the ArcMap GUI (or tools, ModelBuilder or Python, if you prefer)
.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @PolyGeo! I probably won't be doing this again any time soon, but out of curiosity, is this faster than what brad suggested below?

Comment: I suspect speed will be comparable (but have not performance tested) but the advantages I see of this method are that it handles buffer overlap and avoids data duplication.